# Conditional expectation of Uniform given sum of Bernoulli trials

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution, computational-statistics, bernoulli-distribution

Given:
[[image]]

Find the conditional probability distribution of theta given Sn and compute the conditional expectation.

I believe the distribution of Sn will be a binomial with mean n*theta and variance (n*theta)(1-theta). I am not sure how to apply this into Bayes' Theorem to get the conditional distribution of Theta given Sn

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Hint:  Bayes rule

Comment: Alternatively, write down the joint probability and apply the definition of conditional probability.  The simple elementary definitions will work because $\Pr(S_n=4)$ is nonzero.